# Specific User/MAC-address QoS router

Tags: wireless-networking, user-profiles, qos

Not being a fan of WiFi passwords, I wish to have an open network; at least for Guests.

Unfortunately I haven't seen any ability within the current range of WiFi routers to enable QoS for specific users on the network. They're mostly traffic/port derived, and hardly any popular brands are L7 capable.

What would you recommend as the most capable router that would be able to:

- QoS per user
- Guest WiFi (most these days I assume?)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using [Mikrotik](http://routerboard.com/) device with [RouterOS](http://www.mikrotik.com/software.html). Although it takes some knowledge of how things work, to set it up. But it can do both things - per User QoS and multiple SSIDs.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Fox, am actually after an OTS product.